# Why do println(measure + '"'); and println(measure + '\"'); add to measure, while using seperate statements prints correctly?

Tags: java, double-quotes, apostrophe

to test myself in Java, I wrote up a program where I needed to display the contents of `double[] measurements`, containing: {8.0, 7.7474, 7.4949, 7.7474, 8.0, 7.7474, 7.4949, 7.7474, 8.0}. A simple enhanced for loop and a `println()` seems to work fine, but

```
for(double measure: measurements)
{
   System.out.println(measure + '"');
}
```

prints out 42, 41.7474, 41.4949, etc. Exactly 34 more than the value of `measure`. Changing the code to

```
for(double measure: measurements)
{
    System.out.println(measure + '\"');
}
```

prints out 18,17.7474, 17.4949, etc. Exactly 10 more than the correct value. It only prints correctly when the `println` statement is split into two lines:

```
System.out.print(measure);
System.out.println("\"");
```

Why is it that the first two examples add to the value of `measure`? I'm fairly new to programming, but it seems to me that they would all have worked because Java uses both apostrophes and quotes to declare a string. Why does splitting it into two statements work correctly while connotating the two add to the value of `measure`? Thanks!

Comment: `char` is treated like a unsigned short when used in arithmetic.

Comment: _Java uses both apostrophes and quotes to declare a string_ - That's just not true.

Comment: "Java uses both apostrophes and quotes to declare a string." Nope.

Comment: @CollinD Java uses single quotes `'` to denote `char` values. You cannot have multiple chars within single quotes.

Comment: @killjoy I agree!

Comment: I actually completely ignored everything after the -. Oh well.

Comment: Use `String.format()` rather than concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are printing the result of the expression `measure + '"'`. At the moment, you're performing an addition between a `double` and a `char`. If you instead use `"` instead of `'` it will work.

Like this: `System.out.println(measure + "\"");`

Another option is to first convert `measure` to a string. That's rarely the best alternative, but the whole gist here is that you need to know the types of the operands and what the resulting type of the operation will be. Addition between a `double` and a `char` will result in a `double`. Addition between a `double` (or `int` or `char` among others) and a `String` will result in a `String`.

Comment: Or you could just write `measure + "\""`.

Comment: I see. I just assumed that Java used apostrophes the same way as Python, I didn't know that `char`s could be added to doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophes are used to declare `char` not `String` remember that. You can't have more than one char within single quotes.

Just do `measure + "\""`